# Отслеживание значения input

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

Всем добрый день!
при клике на кнопки из за отслеживания по клику число перепрыгивает дальше и сообщение выходит позже.Подскажите как лучше исполнить такую вещь

http://jsfiddle.net/Smak_DSGN/qagmtkL4/

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста тэги и по возможности перенесите код в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Подсказали решение просто нужно было исправить это $('.plus').click(function()  на это $(document).on('click','.plus', function() так же и с кнопкой минус

Answer (score 0):

Первое что пришло в голову.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var numCount = document.getElementById('num_count');
    var plusBtn = document.getElementById('button_plus');
    var minusBtn = document.getElementById('button_minus');

    $('#num_count').keyup(function() {
    if (numCount.value > 3) 
    {
       $('.limit-block').show();
       $(".limit-prod-number").css("border-color", "#F14942")
    } 
    else 
    {
       $('.limit-block').hide();
       $(".limit-prod-number").css("border-color", "#E4E4E4")
    }
    });

    plusBtn.onclick = function() {
      var qty = parseInt(numCount.value);
      qty = qty + 1;
      numCount.value = qty;

      if (qty > 3) 
      {
        $('.limit-block').show();
        $(".limit-prod-number").css("border-color", "#F14942")
      }
      else 
      {
        $('.limit-block').hide();
        $(".limit-prod-number").css("border-color", "#E4E4E4")
      }
    }

    minusBtn.onclick = function() {
      if (numCount.value > 1) {
        var qty = parseInt(numCount.value);
        qty = qty - 1;
        numCount.value = qty;

        if (qty > 3) 
        {
            $('.limit-block').show();
            $(".limit-prod-number").css("border-color", "#F14942")
        } 
        else 
        {
            $('.limit-block').hide();
            $(".limit-prod-number").css("border-color", "#E4E4E4")
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```